# multivariable calculus - find a function such that $\lim_{t \to 0} f(tx,ty)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, multivariable-calculus

I was asked the following question:

Find a function $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x,y)$ has no limit as $x$ and $y$ approach zero, but $\lim_{t\to 0} f(tv)=0$ for all $v \in \mathbb R^2$

I think I misunderstood the question. I mean, the fact that $f$ has no limit as $x,y$ approach zero, doesn't that mean that $\lim_{t \to 0} f(tx,ty)$ doesn't exist?

Comment: $f(x)=x^2y/(x^4+y^2)$, $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$; $f(0,0)=0$.

Comment: The condition means the limit is $0$ along any straight line path through the origin ($f(x,mx)\rightarrow0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. if you consider

$$f(x, y) = \frac{x^2}{y}$$, this has no limit as $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$ basically because $y$ can go to zero really fast (like $x^3$, for instance) so in this case the limit is $\infty$, or they can both go to zero with the same "speed", so the limit is $0$.

$$f(x, x^3) \to \infty$$ but $$f(x, x) \to 0$$.

What the text is saying is basically that $x$ and $y$ going to zero at the same speed (they are both in the form $ta$, where $a$ is a constant)

So

$$f(ta, tb) = t \frac{a^2}{b} \to 0$$

Comment: I think $f$ has to be defined everywhere, here.

Comment: oh, you're right actually. I am sure though the Op can figure out himself after understanding the general principle :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the examples of this using a "single rule" are harder to understand than a piecewise defined example.

Let 
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
      1 \text{ if } y=x^2\\
      0 \text{ if } y \neq x^2
      \end{cases}
$$

Draw a picture of the parabola $y =x^2$.  It is easy to see that for every line passing through the origin, $y \neq x^2$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ along that line.  So the limit is $0$ along each line, but the limit is $1$ if you approach along the parabola.